# Get Last Register User's ID

Tags: 8, users

I am trying to retrieve the details of the last user who registered to the site. There is a similar question here: [How to get the uid of a newly created user?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/236060/how-to-get-the-uid-of-a-newly-created-user)
but it assumes that the registration is also done programmatically, while I don't have any such assumption.

The only way I saw how to do it was to go to the DB directly (not recommended by basically every resource I read). Is there a way to do this through some other interface?

Comment: I don't know if there is a function offhand, but what is wrong with using a database query? You could also execute a View in code and use the result.

Comment: It's just that everywhere I read, it says I shouldn't use the DB object unless absolutely necessary. Just trying to follow best practices :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to query the DB directly, you can use an entity query:

```
$uids = \Drupal::entityQuery('user')
  ->sort('created', 'DESC')
  ->range(0, 1)
  ->execute();
$uid = reset($uids);
```